# Bind application to network adapter or prevent it from using another

Tags: windows-7, network-adapter

On Windows 7 64-bit, I have a problem with Lync disconnecting regularly when my VPN network adapter is present (one of those Juniper Network Connect virtual adapters). I have looked through the Lync logs and no luck so far identifying something that could look like the culprit.

So I am trying to do one of the following:

1) Bind Lync to my wireless network adapter exclusively.
2) Prevent Lync from even seeing the VPN network adapter.

Any ideas on how to achieve one or both?

Thanks you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [ForceBindIP](http://www.r1ch.net/stuff/forcebindip/). However, you may have to disable UAC or run it from an administrator console to make it work.